How to efficiently query BigQuery external table (Bigtable) using keys from a smaller table
I am working with two tables in BigQuery:

qt: A small table (~a few thousand records) with a single string column called rowKey.
tt: A massive external table (~5TB) from Bigtable, accessed through an external table connection in BigQuery.

My goal is to query tt to fetch only the rows where rowKey matches the values in qt.rowKey.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Attempt 1: Using a subquery with IN
SELECT t.*
FROM tt t
WHERE t.rowKey IN (SELECT rowKey FROM qt)

Issue: This query runs indefinitely and does not finish.
Attempt 2: Using a LEFT JOIN
SELECT t.*
FROM qt
LEFT JOIN tt ON tt.rowKey = qt.rowKey

Issue: This query also takes an extremely long time and does not finish.
Attempt 3: Hardcoding a small subset of keys
SELECT t.*
FROM tt
WHERE rowKey IN ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")

Result: This query runs successfully in a few seconds.
It seems like the IN clause or the JOIN is causing a full table scan on the external table (tt). When I hardcode a small set of rowKey values, the query performs as expected.
I want to efficiently query tt for the rowKey values present in qt.rowKey without causing a full scan of the massive tt table.
How can I optimize this query to avoid a full table scan on the tt external table? Are there specific techniques or best practices for querying Bigtable data in BigQuery with filters from a smaller table?

I guess, in your second attempt LEFT JOIN is to be replaced by INNER JOIN

Inner join is a right way of improvement. You can also try a script with a first query to your QT table, then, build a sting like your third attempt , and then run the query with an execute immediate.

I've tried the inner join as well it did not work. the execution graph is still scanning both tables first then joining them


You can also try a script with a first query to your QT table, then, build a sting like your third attempt , and then run the query with an execute immediate.

This could be a last resort solution. However I want to write the output to a table. Doing an update statement will require many of them and it dose not work well on bigquery. I tired this before and I was getting Unable to serialize access to a BigQuery table due to concurrent updates
